# Как повесить обработчик клика на много кнопок в через фреймворк Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

И висит на каждом `div` обработчик, но когда будет таких `div-элементов` 100 штук.

Например: есть какая-то директива, или что-то такое, чтоб 1 раз где-то написать обработчик, и всё, чтоб не вставлять его в каждый `div`?

Вот есть чуть дивов:

```html
<div (click)="checkInfo()">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div (click)="checkInfo()">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div (click)="checkInfo()">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div (click)="checkInfo()">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div (click)="checkInfo()">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно: добавить для всех блоков родителя, на него повесить клик и в методе уже разбирать на что кликнули; если все блоки одинаковые - ngFor, условно, i = 0; i < 10; добавлять блоккам класс и написать метод на js который добавит слушатели и в onInit его вызывать

Comment: @InDevX типу родителю добавить клик, и в методе написать if e .target == 'какой блок надо' то выполнять, так я понял?

Comment: Да, верно понял

Comment: т.е. вам нужно пробегать не по массиву, а в зависимости от какого-то числа создавать определённое количество блоков?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин нет. например у меня в html есть уже 10 блоков. и надо повесить евенти на каждый

Answer (score 0):

Если блоки одинаковые, как указано в примере, то скорее всего их данные можно разместить в массиве, а после отобразить через директиву `ngFor`, и в ней же на каждый блок в цикле навесить метод `(click)`, и передать в него аргументом элемент из цикла, чтобы была привязка к конкретной записи.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="checkInfo(item)">
  <ul>
    <li>{{item | json}}</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```